# Usage of "You are" with a phrase in between

Tags: grammar, phrases

> You are going to be the death of me.

The above is a correct usage. Is it also correct if there's a phrase between you and are?

> You wearing black dresses are going to be the death of me?

Or is the correct form in the modified sentence is:

> You wearing black dresses is going to be the death of me?

Comment: What makes you think the subject-verb agreement of *you are* would change because you insert that phrase in between the two words?

Comment: @Clare it simply doesn't 'feel' right, but it does make sense that it wouldn't change.

Comment: It should be singular "is". "You wearing black dresses" is a non-finite clause and non-finite clauses as subject take singular verb agreement.

Comment: @BillJ thanks! Is there someplace I can read up on these concepts, I'm not entirely familiar with them (non-native speaker).

Comment: My comment applied to the original question, which asked about *You,  wearing black dresses,  are going to be the death of me*. Subsequently  the question has been edited to ask about *You wearing black dresses are going to be the death of me* but in this case the answer is the same: the verb is *are*.

Comment: This question spun out of a similar argument my friend and I had. What would be a way to find the correct convention here?

Comment: From a grammatical point of view the subject could be an NP or a gerund-participial clause, hence either verb-form would be possible. Consider "Women driving cars in Saudi Arabia really **is** a strange sight (clause subject) vs "Women driving cars in Saudi Arabia really **are** a strange sight" (noun phrase subject). I took your example as belonging to the former category (clausal) but the noun phrase analysis is also possible.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say: *You [people who are] wearing black dresses **are** going to be the death of me.* But *[The fact that] you [are] wearing black dresses **is** going to be the death of me.* In either case you should probably rephrase to make your meaning clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> Your wearing black dresses is going to be the death of me.

This needs to be singular.  "Your wearing black dresses" may be thought of as "your custom."

Comment: Lest there be any doubt, whether one uses a possessive in *your wearing* or an (invisible) oblique in *you wearing*, using a nonfinite verb phrase — be it an infinitive or an *-ing* verb — as a subject always commands singular concord with the actual verb. [And not just in English alone, either.](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Concordancia%20del%20verbo%20con%20el%20sujeto.htm) :)

Comment: @tchrist - Please feel free to edit and improve my answer -- if you think it is possible; if not, I won't mind if you write your own....